# What could be the consequences of economic isolation in a medieval post-apocalyptic fantasy setting?

Tags: magic, economy, medieval, post-apocalypse, isolation

I'm running an RPG campaign (using 
[Fantasy Age](http://greenroninstore.com/products/fantasy-age-basic-rulebook) rules) in a medieval setting, a few generations after a sort of apocalypse happened. The region the characters are in is the one that was least affected by it, so everyone who could manage to get there did so, leading to overpopulation. The region has an unnatural though not infinite food production and plenty of drinkable water and mineral resources, but what they manage to produce is not enough to generate surplus. Also, since other communities lie far away across a barren, dangerous land, the possibilities of trade are close to zero.
Magic exists in this world and it's uncommon though not rare, but it has many potential dangers and drawbacks.
There are many dangerous creatures and marauders about, so a good measure of their resources go to maintaining a powerful military organization.

Would a place like this have any use for coin? If so, would they keep on producing coin, or would they only use the coin they already had (thus probably increasing it's value)?

How would their internal market work? What sort of products would be available?

How would people who do not own land manage to make a living? Hunting outside the communities is possible but dangerous and there isn't a whole lot of prey available.

Comment: Depends upon the food source. There is a reasonable chance that the unnatural food source might become the currency.

Comment: Does your setting have everything it needs within its borders to survive and is not dependent on a really rare but crucial item to survive?  This scenario reminds me of "Attack on Titan" where almost all resources are scarce because the community has been living behind walls for centuries.

Answer (score 1):

> Would a place like this have any use for coin? If so, would they keep on producing coin, or would they only use the coin they already had (thus probably increasing it's value)?

It depends of the size and complexity of market. If you have lots of hamlets which each produce the same products, there is little interest in trade and so bartering (and taxes in products and services) may be enough. If you have lots of trade of different products and/or a complex hierarchy, then coin begins being more useful. And of course you can have mixed systems (trade inside the hamlet is done with bartering, selling surplus brings coins that can be used to pay taxes and trade for more elaborated goods).

For the second question, depends if they have access to a source of bullion for the coin. Even if you don't produce more, it does not mean that deflation will happen; deflation will happen only if the amount of coins remains stable while the supply of goods increases (either because more effective techniques are developed or because previously unused resources/workforce) are movilized. And even in the worst case (you have increased good supplies and no source of bullion) you can always debase the coins.

> How would their internal market work? What sort of products would be available?

Umm? That's what you have to decide, based in climate and technology/magic. Most production will go towards foodstuffs, depending of type and conservation technologies more or less will be need to be transformed into easier-to-conserve products. The more homogeneus, the less need for trade; and the more trade, the more probability of having some regions specializing in certains kinds of products and or industries (textiles, etc.)

> How would people who do not own land manage to make a living? Hunting outside the communities is possible but dangerous and there isn't a whole lot of prey available.

As always:

- Working the fields for people who owns land.
- Working as servants for people who owns lots of land.
- Military/enforcement (would be basically the same).
- Trade.
- Outlaws.
- Entertainers, etc...

Answer (score 0):

So you need a constant standing military in a region with a food deficit. This means people are going hungry. Who is going hungry? That depends on the social situation. Its not the military or the elites since they have control over the food. Now which of the remaining factions are left hungry kind of depends on everyones place in your society.

The coin thing has been answered quite well so I won't go into it. You'll have to decide what happens to beggars. By beggars I mean anyone who cant hold down a job for whatever reason, they're crippled, or have special needs, whatever. They may be killed, they may find use as explorers since its super dangerous. Dunno. But there isn't any food and no resources for charity.

The lack of outside trade doesn't really affect them unless there is some good or service that can't be reproduced. Considering they have survivors from all the lands there shouldn't be a skills shortage. Unless there is therefore a resource shortage the only issue with the lack of trade is the food shortage.

Internal market then should have all the stuff that is available in the region. It probably wont have high quality finished goods because many of the artisans have recently arrived and have had to rebuild a workshop from scraps. Unless it was being built here before the apocalypse its going to be low-quality. Other than that I don't see it being different from any other market, food, goods and services are exchanged for each other on the basis of supply and demand of each.